# Display multiple MySQL records in separate divs

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am trying to create an auto-suggest system to query MySQL and display possible options to the user as they type. Everything is working fine up until one of the options are clicked. When alerted out via jQuery, a block of text containing all the queried records are passed, instead of just the one being clicked.

This is the PHP:

```
$query=$conn->query("SELECT * from Customers where Phone like '%$searchq%' limit 10") or die($conn->error);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

$fname = $row['FName'];
$lname = $row['LName'];
$add01 = $row['Address 01'];
$add02 = $row['Address 02'];
$suburb = $row['Suburb'];
$state = $row['State'];
$pcode = $row['Postcode'];
$phone = $row['Phone'];
$email = $row['Email'];

$output.= '<div name="firstdiv" class="redata" style="width:auto;text-align:left;text-decoration:none;color:black;">'.$phone.' '.$fname.' '.$lname.' '.$add01.' '.$add02.' '.$suburb.' '.$state.' '.$pcode.' '.$email.'</div>';

echo $output;

$mysqli->close;
```

$output then gets sent to the following html:

```
<div name="seconddiv" class="seconddiv" id="seconddiv" style="height:auto;width:auto;margin-top:60px;float:left;font-family:Verdana;font-size:14px;color:black;position:absolute;display:none;z-index:10000;border-radius:7px;border:1px solid navy;background-color:rgba(184,204,228,0.3);padding:7px;">
<div name="thirddiv" class="thirddiv" id="thirddiv" style="height:auto;width:auto;text-decoration:none;text-align:left;color:solid black;border:2px solid red;"></div>
```

Which is then alerted out by the following jQuery:

```
$('#thirddiv').click(function()  {
clientdets = $('#thirddiv').text(); 
alert(clientdets);
});
```

And finally, the result I'm getting concatenates all records, and displays them all in one big chunk in the alert message box.

What I need is to be able to click a single div, and for the contents of that div alone to be alerted out, instead of the whole lot.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, for the sake of my dwindling hair, which I've been pulling out over the last few days now over this.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you have an html structure something like this:

```
<div id="thirddiv">
   <div>text example 1</div>
   <div>text example 2</div>
   <div>text example 3</div>
   ...
</div>
```

Your event handler should then be rewritten to something like this:

```
$("#thirddiv").find("div").on("click", function()  {
   clientdets = $(this).text(); 
   alert(clientdets);
});
```

Notice, that I have used the `id` attribute instead of the `name` attribute here.

As an aside, inline styling should probably be avoided. Use a separate css stylesheet instead.

Comment: Thanks Miqi180, I take your point about inline styling, but am just in the habit of doing that when I am developing, and then moving it all to a separate style sheet when I'm done.

The div structure is at present as I have illustrated, and that could be where the problem is. 

Is there a way to pass individual records returned by MySQL to each of the child divs you've shown, which would increase/decrease dynamically in number depending on the number of records being returned?

Comment: There certainly is. You could use jQuery's load function for that or $.post if you need to send data before any is returned and then add the divs+content dynamically to the DOM with .append in the callback function. Regarding css, I suppose it's a matter of working style, but I tend to think it's double work to do what you're doing here... :)

Comment: Brilliant, and ofcourse there has to be, because I've seen this sort of thing done many times. In case you haven't guessed, I am a bit of a novice, and will now go off to research load & .append. Thanks very much for providing some direction!

Comment: Ok, a whole day later, and I'm no better off! I think the problem is that the php bit is concatenating all the records being extracted from mysql, and forcing the whole lot to #thirddiv. I need a way to separate the concat between records, and for them to be passed to divs created dynamically to accommodate however many records there are (replicants of #thirddiv?), mimicking a listbox, that are then alerted separately when clicked. Anyone with any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

Got rid of the JQuery event handler all together, and modified the final line in the php  section to:

```
echo '<li name="outputerator" class="redata" style="width:auto;text-align:left;text-decoration:none;color:black;border:2px solid green;"onclick="alert($(this).text());">'.$phone.' '.$fname.' '.$lname.''.$add01.''.$add02.' '.$suburb.' '.$state.' '.$pcode.' '.$email.'</li>';
```

And changed `#Thirddiv` to a `<ul>`.
Yay me! :-)